# Rails: ignoring duplicates in an nested association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have models `User`, `Team`, `Document`. There's a many-to-many relationship between Users and Teams, and a many-to-many relationship between Teams and Documents, using join tables called `TeamMembership` and `TeamDocument` respectively.

The relationships in my models look like this:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_documents, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :teams, through: :team_documents
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_memberships, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :member_id
  has_many :teams, through: :team_memberships
  has_many :documents, through: :teams
end

class TeamDocument < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :document
end

class TeamMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :member, class_name: "User"
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_documents, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :documents, through: :team_documents
  has_many :team_memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :members, through: :team_memberships
end
```

The idea is that users can belong to many teams, a document can be associated with many teams, and users will only have access to documents that "belong" to at least one team that the user is a member of.

Here's the question: I can use `User#documents` to retrieve a list of all the documents that this user is allowed to view. But this will return duplicates if a document is viewable by more than one team which the user is a member of. How can I avoid this?

I know I can remove the duplicates after the fact with `@user.documents.uniq`, but as I will **never** want to include the duplicates in any case, is there a way I can just make `#documents` not include duplicates every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have nested `has_many :through` like yours to test it, but I suspect using `uniq` option on your user association would help :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents, through: :teams, uniq: true
end
```

Comment: aaaaaand after upgrading to Rails 4 I get a notice that `uniq: true` is deprecated. Fixed it by changing the line to `has_many :documents, -> { uniq }, through: :teams`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default_scope on Document model:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base

default_scope group: { documents: :id }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. As you wrote it, I get `NameError: undefined local variable or method \`id'`. If I change `id` to `:id`, I get an error from PostGres: `column reference "id" is ambiguous`.